# Stop JW Player duration display counter from counting down?

Tags: jwplayer

I'm using JWPlayer version 7 to play both video and audio files on my site. Is there an option in JWPlayer to format the duration display so that it always shows the full duration of the audio or video being played instead of counting down?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.jw-text-duration` instead of `.jw-text-elapsed` to display the full duration in the control bar.

https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/css-skinning-reference.html